# Zepto Virus check - Scan A Server/PC Disk Drive looking for part of a filename

Tags: vbscript

Im looking for some help with creating a script that can scan the Disk Drives on a Server or PC and search out a Zepto Virus infection and alert us in our Monitoring Dashboard.

We have used scripts to detect Cryptowall and Locky but these rely on searching for a very specific file name. The difference with Zepto is that its "Help" files are composed with a random number in each file:

_3_HELP_instructions.html, _21_HELP_instructions.html, _12_HELP_instructions.html etc.

Essentially im looking for a script that can maybe search for *_HELP_instructions.html or even just search for any filename with HELP_instructions.html contained in it.

The code we have used for Locky is as follows:

```
strComputer = "." 
    set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
       & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
    Set colShares = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Share") 

For each objShare in colShares 
    strInfected = False  
    If objFSO.fileexists(objShare.path & "\_Locky_recover_instructions.txt") then 
        strInfected = True 
        wscript.echo "Network Share " & objShare.Path & " is INFECTED!" 
        wscript.quit(2015) 
    End If 
Next 

If strInfected = False Then 
    wscript.echo "System Clear!" 
    wscript.quit(0) 
End If
```

Is there anyone out there that can help me with this one? due to the way our Monitoring Dashboard works i need the script to be based on the above, with the:

```
If strInfected = False Then 
    wscript.echo "System Clear!" 
    wscript.quit(0) 
End If
```

at the end of the script.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Hi All, has anyone has any joy with this?